# How do you add some padding to items of a ListView in flutter without hiding parts of the items?

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a ListView which renders rows. I want to have some space between the rows but as soon as I add some padding parts the padding makes part of the row invisible.

What can I do to have some space between the items of a ListView?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  var wateringPeriods = new List<WateringPeriod>();
  initState() {
      super.initState();

      _getWateringPeriods();
    }

  Widget _listItemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index)
  {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: Row 
      (
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
          Text( "some Text"),
          Text("some othe Text"),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              print("filled background");
              }
            )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: 
         Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[   
                Expanded(
                  child:ListView.builder(
                  itemCount:wateringPeriods.length,
                    itemExtent:30,
                    itemBuilder: _listItemBuilder
                    )
                )
            ]
          )
      );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want some spacing in between each item in the list, or spacing between the widgets in a single row?

Comment: The spacing is needed between the list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `itemExtent: 30,` probably fixes the problem